# Is it possible to run GlassFish 4.1.x with AdoptOpenJDK 8 (or Zulu)?

Tags: java-8, glassfish, adoptopenjdk

As anyone familiar with my question is probably aware, Oracle JDK 8 is no longer receiving public updates for free. My dev team deploys applications through GlassFish 4.1.1, which we know and love, but we are nervous about its continued use given that we can't get public JDK updates through Oracle anymore.

I've done a little background research which looks to imply that AdoptOpenJDK may well work with GlassFish, but there is no clear guidance online as far as I can see from either Oracle or Eclipse. There does look to be a couple of posts suggesting users have made it work with Zulu - but the lack of official guidance is frustrating and confusing.

The question I'm specifically asking here is has anyone actually got any real **production** deployments of GlassFish running with AdoptOpenJDK (or failing that, Zulu)?

I'm hoping we can find a relatively simple swap-out solution for moving from Oracle JDK to AdoptOpenJDK or similar without having to re-install GlassFish.

As a side note, I'm also aware that GlassFish 5.2 is in the pipeline which hopefully should support a JDK from Jakarta EE as and when that arrives - but I really need a solution that I can implement now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

GlassFish (and Payara) work fine using OpenJDK or Azul or any other JDK.

Source: Our company is using Azul Java 8 with support.